# Create Amazon EC2 Instance with API

Tags: java, amazon-ec2

Does com.amazonaws.services.ec2 contain a method to create a brand new EC2 instance from an existing AMI?  I'm looking to do this from the Java SDK, not the web management console.

Comment: Clear and simple article on that: http://codeflex.co/java-aws-sdk-create-and-run-ec2-instance/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

RunInstances is the method, it should be in the SDK.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I'm also need an ability to distinguish instances I start from all of my other ones.  Do you know of a good way to do this?

Comment: You have a few options.  Easiest way is to add a tag to your instances created in code (you're limited to 10 total tags per instance, though) with CreateTags; these are then returned from DescribeInstances along with your instances (and also viewable in the web console)

Answer (score 69):

Here is a sample to create EC2 Instances with Amazon AWS SDK for Java :

```
// CONNECT TO EC2

InputStream credentialsAsStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("AwsCredentials.properties");
Preconditions.checkNotNull(credentialsAsStream, "File 'AwsCredentials.properties' NOT found in the classpath");
AWSCredentials credentials = new PropertiesCredentials(credentialsAsStream);

AmazonEC2 ec2 = new AmazonEC2Client(credentials);
ec2.setEndpoint("ec2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com");

// CREATE EC2 INSTANCES
RunInstancesRequest runInstancesRequest = new RunInstancesRequest()
    .withInstanceType("t1.micro")
    .withImageId("ami-62201116")
    .withMinCount(2)
    .withMaxCount(2)
    .withSecurityGroupIds("tomcat")
    .withKeyName("xebia-france")
    .withUserData(Base64.encodeBase64String(myUserData.getBytes()))
;

RunInstancesResult runInstances = ec2.runInstances(runInstancesRequest);

// TAG EC2 INSTANCES
List<Instance> instances = runInstances.getReservation().getInstances();
int idx = 1;
for (Instance instance : instances) {
  CreateTagsRequest createTagsRequest = new CreateTagsRequest();
  createTagsRequest.withResources(instance.getInstanceId()) //
      .withTags(new Tag("Name", "travel-ecommerce-" + idx));
  ec2.createTags(createTagsRequest);

  idx++;
}
```

Source code (create RDS, EC2 and ELB instances) is available at http://code.google.com/p/xebia-france/source/browse/training/xebia-spring-travel/trunk/xebia-spring-travel-amazon-aws/src/main/java/fr/xebia/demo/amazon/aws/AmazonAwsInfrastructureMaker.java?spec=svn1781&r=1781

Hope this helps,

Cyrille

Answer (score 0):

```
 var launchRequest = new RunInstancesRequest()
                {
                    ImageId = amiID,
                    InstanceType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AwsInstanceType"],
                    MinCount = 1,
                    MaxCount = 1,
                    KeyName = keyPairName,
                    SecurityGroupIds = groups,
                    SubnetId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AwsSubnetId"],

                };
                RunInstancesResponse runInstancesResponse = amazonEc2client.RunInstances(launchRequest);
                var InstanceId = runInstancesResponse.Reservation.Instances[0].InstanceId;
                var trequest = new CreateTagsRequest();
                trequest.Resources=new List<string>(){InstanceId};
                List<Tag> tags=new List<Tag>();
                Tag tag=new Tag("Name","TestCodeFinal");
                tags.Add(tag);
                trequest.Tags = tags;
                amazonEc2client.CreateTags(trequest);
                Reservation reservation = runInstancesResponse.Reservation;
```

Comment: the above is C# and not Java.