# How to start and stop an Amazon EC2 instance programmatically in java

Tags: java, amazon-ec2

How do i start and stop an amazon [EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instance programmatically using aws-sdk in java?

Any helps are greatly appreciated as I have spent a day while trying to sort this out.

Comment: Here's how to create one; http://stackoverflow.com/a/6504009/477878

Comment: we are not interested in creation, but to start/stop an already existing instance. so there is a difference

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've recently implemented this functionality within the [Bamboo AWS Plugin](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/774227); it's Open Source and the [code is available on Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/utoolity/bamboo-aws-plugin), you can find a complete example how to start/stop/reboot an instance within [EC2Task.java](https://bitbucket.org/utoolity/bamboo-aws-plugin/src/ef5a1a97df2c/src/main/java/net/utoolity/bamboo/plugins/EC2Task.java) (should be a separate class actually, alas ...).

Fortunately this is not complicated at all, for example, an instance can be started like so:

```
private String startInstance(final String instanceId, AmazonEC2 ec2, final BuildLogger buildLogger)
        throws AmazonServiceException, AmazonClientException, InterruptedException
{
    StartInstancesRequest startRequest = new StartInstancesRequest().withInstanceIds(instanceId);
    StartInstancesResult startResult = ec2.startInstances(startRequest);
    List<InstanceStateChange> stateChangeList = startResult.getStartingInstances();
    buildLogger.addBuildLogEntry("Starting instance '" + instanceId + "':");

    // Wait for the instance to be started
    return waitForTransitionCompletion(stateChangeList, "running", ec2, instanceId, buildLogger); }
```

BuildLogger is Bamboo specific and [waitForTransitionCompletion()](https://bitbucket.org/utoolity/bamboo-aws-plugin/src/ef5a1a97df2c/src/main/java/net/utoolity/bamboo/plugins/EC2Task.java#cl-233) is an implementation specific  helper to report back on the process/result. The `AmazonEC2 ec2` parameter passes the reference to an [AmazonEC2Client](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2Client.html) object by means of the [AmazonEC2](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2.html) interface, which defines all relevant methods (amongst many others), specifically:

- [StartInstances()](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2.html#startInstances%28com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.StartInstancesRequest%29)
- [StopInstances()](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2.html#stopInstances%28com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.StopInstancesRequest%29)
- [RebootInstances()](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2.html#rebootInstances%28com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.RebootInstancesRequest%29)

Answer (score 7):

If you have already used [AWS API](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html), it's simple call on [AmazonEC2Client](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2Client.html) object. Use the following methods

- [Start Instance](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2Client.html#startInstances%28com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.StartInstancesRequest%29)
- [Stop Instance](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2Client.html#stopInstances%28com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.StopInstancesRequest%29)

Also, you might be knowing the start/stop mechanism works **only** for the images with root device backed by EBS.