# How can I "Start" and "Reboot" AWS EC2 Instances?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When we open AWS Management Console, then select Instances then to turn On/Start any instance we right click on that instance and select "Start" and same is the process to Reboot an instance. Reference Image attached.

So My Question is how can I accomplish the above stated tasks programmatically from java application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to start and stop an Amazon EC2 instance programmatically in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951205/how-to-start-and-stop-an-amazon-ec2-instance-programmatically-in-java)